# The height of the video tag, depending on the width of the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please tell me how you can implement this possibility, depending on the width of the browser screen, the height of the video tag always kept 70%. Through css, I could not do it.
The video itself is on the full width of my screen. I would like to do this on js

```
<div class="video-cont">
        <div class="overlay-video"></div>
     <video src="https://globecore.com/wp-content/themes/globecore2016/video/usa-lp-video.mp4" type="mp4" autoplay="true" loop="loop"></video>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.video-cont {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: -32px;
    position: relative;
}
.overlay-video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    right: 0px;
    height: 670px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 8;
}
```

Comment: You want video height to be 70% of viewport width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set sizes like `vw` or `vh` which is the viewportWidth or viewportHeight

```css
.video-cont {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: -32px;
    position: relative;
}
.overlay-video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    right: 0px;
    height: 670px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 8;
}

.video-cont video {
    height: 70vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="video-cont">
        <div class="overlay-video"></div>
     <video src="https://globecore.com/wp-content/themes/globecore2016/video/usa-lp-video.mp4" type="mp4" autoplay="true" loop="loop"></video>
    </div>
```

Comment: @АлександрПивень glad it helped, happy coding

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this css code:

```
video {height: 70vw;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the browser screen width in javascript by using `window.screen.width` or `screen.width` and then do the necessary calculations.